# Setting the clickable and try icon in GTK+

Tags: c++, configuration, icons, gtk

I am coding a quick program in Gtk+ and would like to create a custom icon. The standard icon in the top left hand corner is the GTK logo in three colors. How would a change the standard icon?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Gtk3, you can do either of two things:

- You can, if using the GtkApplication object, read [the top section of the the GtkApplication docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html) which explain how to create a desktop file and where to put your icon. I think most people will not be using GtkApplication, so more likely will be option 2.
- If you are using a simple GtkWindow, which is more likely, you can use [`gtk_window_set_icon()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-icon) and [`gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/unstable/gdk-pixbuf-File-Loading.html#gdk-pixbuf-new-from-file).